# How do I enlarge a buttons image?

Tags: uibutton, uiimage, interface-builder

I want this image (which is a button) to be a little bigger and by dragging the corners I make the button bigger but the image itself doesnt scale. Setting constraints for width and height doesnt help either.

**How can I enlarge the image of the button?**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have added the image as button's image property. Whenyou set an image as button's image property, it becomes the button title image and title image wont change its size with size of the button :)

If you want the image to change its size with button size set the image as buttons background :)

Keep in mind setting image to button's background, image will change its size with button but image may distort if you stretch image too much.

If you are adding image on top of button by any chance... hmmmm... thats a pretty bad way of doing it buddy. Try either button image or background property :)

Happy coding :)

Comment: that worked but just on the UIBuilder when I launch the simulator images stay their size and dont scale :(

Comment: Ok are you aware of intrnsic sizes? UIButton takes the size based on either the title text or title image or background image size based on whichever is present n whichever is large in size :) now in your case you can add image as button background drag it to whatever size required and then add height width constraint to it buddy :)

Comment: by adding constraint you will override the intrinsic size of the button :) and it will obey your auto layout constraint :)